# Using raw_input in pascal's triangle

Tags: python, pascals-triangle

I was looking at a post by Don Marco that involved making Pascal's Triangle in python. I wanted to understand the code better so I tried played with it and tried to have it take a user input. This is the code   I used:

```
def triangle(rows):
    row_ans= raw_input('how many rows would you like')
    row_ans =int(row_ans)
    for rownum in range (rows):
        newValue=1
        PrintingList = [newValue]
        for iteration in range (rownum):
            newValue = newValue * ( rownum-iteration ) * 1 / ( iteration + 1 )
            PrintingList.append(int(newValue))
        print(PrintingList)
    print()
triangle(row_ans)
```

It didn't ask for any user input and I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/centralcity/Desktop/Computer Science!/Pascal's triangle", line 13, in 
<module>          
    triangle(row_ans)
  File "/Users/centralcity/Desktop/Computer Science!/Pascal's triangle", line 3, in       
  triangle      
for rownum in range (rows):
    TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got str.
```

please keep in mind I'm fairly new too python. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the wrong parameter to `range()`. Try this in the outermost `for` loop:

```
range(row_ans)
```

Also notice that the `rows` parameter is not being used, delete it from the function declaration and simply call the function like this:

```
triangle()
```

Comment: I got this error, thanks for helping me solve part of the problem:                                                Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/centralcity/Desktop/Computer Science!/Pascal's triangle", line 13, in <module>
    triangle(row_ans)
NameError: name 'row_ans' is not defined

Comment: @user3163789 of course, the error is very clear: when you call `triangle(rowans)` the variable `row_ans` doesn't exist yet. See my edit answer.

Comment: @user3163789 if the above solves your problem, please don't forget to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) this answer, by clicking on the check mark to the left ;)

Comment: That helped a lot thanks :) I'd vote your answer but I don't have enough reputation points.